# psutil.net_connections() should return namedtuple, but it is not behaving as one

Tags: python, filter, psutil

I'm trying to find out if my server (should be running on `127.0.0.1:5000`) is actually running. I'm trying to use `psutil.net_connections()` to figure it out:

```
filter(lambda conn: conn.raddr.ip == '127.0.0.1' and conn.raddr.port == 5000, psutil.net_connections())
```

This should give me the item corresponds to my server, and to check if I actually got something, I just check the `len(tuple(...)))`. However, using the `tuple(...)` gives me `AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'ip'` which I don't get, since the inner tuple (i.e. `conn.raddr` does have an "ip" attr).

This happens also when looping regularly:

```
In [22]: for conn in psutil.net_connections():
    ...:     if conn.raddr.ip == '127.0.0.1' and conn.raddr.port == 5000:
    ...:         break
    ...: else:
    ...:     print('server is down')
```

**BUT** when using it like this, it works!

```
In [23]: a=psutil.net_connections()[0]
In [24]: a.raddr.ip
Out[24]: '35.190.242.205'
```

*psutil version: 5.7.2*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not all `raddr` have an `ip` attribute. The documentation says:

> `raddr`: the remote address as a `(ip, port)` named tuple or an absolute path in case of UNIX sockets. When the remote endpoint is not connected you’ll get an empty tuple `(AF_INET*)` or `""` (AF_UNIX). For UNIX sockets see notes below.

So you should check that `raddr` not empty before trying to access the `ip` and `port` attributes.

```
filter(lambda conn: conn.raddr and conn.raddr.ip == '127.0.0.1' and conn.raddr.port == 5000, psutil.net_connections())
```